# Find all references of a function in a program

Tags: ida

I was wondering if there is a way to search all references/usages of a function in IDA without having to the run the binary?

I.e I would like to know all the places `PathFindFileNameW` function is called. I can see that the function is used under **Imports** but not sure how to jump to the place where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Press `CTRL-X` with your cursor over the item in question to see a list of its incoming cross-references, as in: [image: this screenshot]

Comment: I presume, you are doing this under "View-A" Tab. I don't even know the first occurence of the function I am looking for. But I don't get anything on pressing CRTL+X, while under Imports tabs and selecting the function.

Comment: If you're in the imports window, double-click on the import that you're interested in. It will take you to another window, in which you'll be able to make use of the advice I gave above.